# Cloud Functions with Cloud SQL - Property 'socketPath' does not exist on type

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to access my Google Cloud SQL database on my Firebase Functions. I followed the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql) but it's not very good and leaves out a lot of information.

I added the code from the docs to my `src\index.ts` file and filled in my data:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connectionName =
  process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME || 'test';
const dbUser = process.env.SQL_USER || 'test';
const dbPassword = process.env.SQL_PASSWORD || 'test';
const dbName = process.env.SQL_NAME || 'test';

const mysqlConfig = {
  connectionLimit: 1,
  user: dbUser,
  password: dbPassword,
  database: dbName,
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  mysqlConfig.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;
}

// Connection pools reuse connections between invocations,
// and handle dropped or expired connections automatically.
let mysqlPool;

exports.mysqlDemo = (req, res) => {
  // Initialize the pool lazily, in case SQL access isn't needed for this
  // GCF instance. Doing so minimizes the number of active SQL connections,
  // which helps keep your GCF instances under SQL connection limits.
  if (!mysqlPool) {
    mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);
  }

  mysqlPool.query('SELECT NOW() AS now', (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
      console.log("Connected!")
    }
  });

  // Close any SQL resources that were declared inside this function.
  // Keep any declared in global scope (e.g. mysqlPool) for later reuse.
};
```

I then tried publishing this to see if it would work, and I got the error:

> Module 'mysql' is not listed as dependency in package.json

So I installed `mysql` by doing `npm install mysql`

and I ran it again and this time I get the error:

> src/index.ts(23,15): error TS2339: Property 'socketPath' does not exist on type '{ connectionLimit: number; user: string; password: string; database: string; }'

What's going on? Have I installed this correctly? I'm very lost and the docs don't seem to offer much of a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a TypeScript error, where the interface for your config object is being inferred and then you're trying to add an extra field on that object that wasn't declared. In other words, the example code from Google is JavaScript, you're using TypeScript and running into a TS error.

I *think* that you should be able to adjust the declaration of `mysqlConfig` to include a `socketPath` property (set to `null`) and all should be OK. In other words, change the `mysqlConfig` definition to:

```
const mysqlConfig = {
  connectionLimit: 1,
  user: dbUser,
  password: dbPassword,
  database: dbName,
  socketPath: null
};
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Seems strange that Google didn't mention that in the docs..